# Should I create a new question when I am offering a bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounties, views

Yesterday I offered a bounty on my question that is several months old. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824070/datepicker-value-set-error-binding-to-datasource).

However there have been only 3 more visits since yesterday - so the bounty appears not to be creating more attention.

Should I have asked a new question instead?

Comment: No. Give it time, the more the expiry date comes closer, the more views you'll probably get.

Comment: We are here to fix problems. Not create them.

Comment: Let me get this straight. You are asking if you should ask a new question _and_ offer a bounty if your question is a [Tumbleweed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/tumbleweed)?

Comment: It isn't quite a tumbleweed because I answered it myself, but recently I deleted the answer because I realised it was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I have asked a new question instead?

Creating a duplicate should never be considered an option and the latest question will be closed or merged to the first one anyway. This will only cause more work for the moderators and the community itself.

All that could have done has been done. The only thing that you can do now is wait: generally bounties that are going to expire soon are viewed more than any other.

In any case here's some generic useful tips to improve your question and get a chance to get more views:

- Use tags
- Improve the quality of your question
- Cut away phrases that are useless
- Answer to comments
- Downvote answers that hasn't been useful
- Flag answers that are very low quality or not *answers*

Comment: +1, but comments don't bump questions.

Comment: @Doorknob, fixed (I've always thought they did)

Answer (score 0):

I placed a bounty on someone else's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232504/navigator-is-not-working-properly-in-stock-chart-for-column-type).

I had similar doubts, as no one seemed to display any interest in it, it was as the due date got closer, there were some comments, I then asked, in the comments, for an answer and got one.

The idea behind a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) is to either get an answer, or better answers for a question, not to change the question.

For more detail on [bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).